# how to make a SAS macro can run a list of variables automatically

Tags: macros, sas

I am using a SAS macro that using a sql into to build a CODELIST and then add a flag into the data. So the format table contains ICD codes and some variable flags name. So this macro basically is just does if I input one flagName it will create a flag variable in the mydata.

```
%MACRO flag(flagName); 
PROC SQL;
    SELECT QUOTE(ICD) INTO :CODELIST SEPARATED BY "," 
        FROM Format_Table
        WHERE FLAG = %unquote(%str(%')&flagName%str(%'));
QUIT;


DATA mydata; SET mydata;
    IF DIAG IN (&CODELIST) THEN &flagName = 1;
RUN;
%MEND flag;
```

However it won't be able to works so well when I have too many flagNames, which means I have to input each variable names one by one. And the falgNames are all diseases names like breast, prostate etc. I am wondering if there is a way that can create a array with the variable names and run the macro with array value each time instead of listing all the macro commands. 
Like:

```
  Array variables [I] breast prostate lung;
  %DO I = 1 to DIM(variables);
  %macro(inputVarialeName = variables[I]);
  END;
```

Please help me if there is a way to do that. Thank you very much for your helps.

Comment: What does the macro do?  Also use another name for your macro as you cannot call it `macro` as that conflicts with `%macro` statement that is used to define a macro.  Do you just want a way to generate a series of macro calls? There should be many examples in documentation and on-line.

Comment: the macro is used to create flags by using proc sql with into and data step. So I have to use where in sql command for each variables so that I could create flags. Would you like to provided a example to do that? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a macro it might be easiest to just change the macro to support multiple flags at once.  You could keep the logic the same and just add some macro loops.

```
%macro flag(flaglist);
%local flagname i n &flaglist;
%let n=%sysfunc(countw(&flaglist));

proc sql noprint;
%do i=1 %to &n ;
  %let flagname=%scan(&flaglist,&i);
  %let &flagname='Not Found';
  select quote(trim(icd)) into :&flagname separated by ','
    from format_table
    where flag = "&flagname"
  ;
%end;
quit;

data mydata;
  set mydata;
%do i=1 %to &n ;
  %let flagname=%scan(&flaglist,&i);
  &flagname = diag in (&&&flagname);
%end;
run;
%mend flag;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CALL EXECUTE and the documentation has a fully worked example [here](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n1q1527d51eivsn1ob5hnz0yd1hx.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).

First you need to create a list of variables somehow, either type it out or pull it from SASHELP.VCOLUMN or PROC CONTENTS.

```
/********************************************************************
Example : Call macro using parameters from data set
********************************************************************/

proc sort data=sashelp.class out=class;
by age sex;
run;

%macro summary(age=, sex=);

proc print data=sashelp.class;
    where age=&age and sex="&sex";
run;

%mend;

data sample;
set class;
by age sex;

if last.sex;
string =
    catt('%summary(age=', age, ',sex=', sex, ');');
put string;
run;


data _null_;
set sample;
call execute(string);
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a second macro that loops over the input and invokes the other macro for each item.

You should really post working code, `%macro (inputVarialeName = v1);` is a bit non-sensical -- are you defining or invoking ?.  `%my_macro (inputVarialeName = v1);` would have been more clear as invoking.

Suppose you have a macro that needs to be invoked multiple times

```
%macro my_macro (var=);
  /* generate some data step code that does something with &var, lets log it */
  putlog 'NOTE: ' &var=;
%mend;
```

or maybe the macro is for some SQL snippet that converts fractions to percents

```
%macro my_macro (var=);
  , &var * 100 as &var._pct
%mend;
```

or is a define statement for `Proc REPORT`

```
%macro my_macro (var=);
  define &var / center;
%mend;
```

Create a second macro that accepts a space separated list of variables, much like a `VAR` statement does in procedures.

```
%macro do_my_macro_for_each (vars=);
  %local index token;
  %let index = 1;
  %do %while (1);
    %let token = %scan(&vars, &index);
    %if %length(&token) = 0 %then %return;

    /* invoke my macro using i-th token */
    %my_macro (var=&token)

    %let index = %eval (&index + 1);
  %end;
%mend;
```

Then invoke the 'do-er' with your list of variables

```
data have;
  array v(1000) (1:1000);
run;

data _null_;
  set have;
  %do_my_macro_for_each (vars=v1 v32 v185 v237);
run;

----- LOG -----
NOTE: v1=1
NOTE: v32=32
NOTE: v185=185
NOTE: v237=237
NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set WORK.HAVE.
```

Other discussions of implementing SAS macro code that does generic for-each processing can be found through internet search or [SAS conference paper searches](https://www.lexjansen.com/) (lexjansen.com)

Comment: I am sorry that my previous version of request is too general and I add some more detail on the description. Thank you for provide this great thoughts but since my macro is already have a sql and data procedure so I won't be able to put that within another data step. Would you mind to provided some thoughts on how to do this? thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  It does change the possible answers in a significant way.  I would recommend *not* running one step per flag name, instead perhaps have one SQL with one select clause per flag.

Answer (score 0):

Qimeng has a table of ICD classifications that will be used to set a presence flag.

```
data DX_CLASSES;
length ICD $5 flag $32;
input 
ICD & Flag ; datalines; /* NOTE: & requires data values be separated by 2 or more spaces */
1     xxx
23.1  xxx
2     yyy
2.1   yyy
3.3   yyy
run;
```

And has some patient diagnosis information

```
data DIAGNOSES;
length pat_id visit_id diagnosis $5;
input
pat_id & visit_id & diagnosis & record_id; datalines;
 1       1          23.1        1
 1       1          2           2
 1       1          77.7        3
 1       2          23.1        4
 2       1          2.1         5
 run;
```

And wants to add one column per distinct flag value.  *It would domain appropriate to consider the phrase 'flag' as 'medical concept'*

```
 pat_id visit_id diagnosis record_id xxx  yyy
 ------ -------- --------- --------- ---  ---
 1      1        23.1      1          1    0
 1      1        2         2          0    1
 1      1        77.7      3          0    0
 1      2        23.1      4          1    0
 2      1        2.1       5          0    1
```

A single SQL could apply the classification lookup for each distinct.  This plain SQL statement can be used as the basis for developing an appropriate macro that is repeatedly invoked.  The `EXISTS` condition works as an efficient `IN` look up evaluation.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select have.* 
  , exists (select * from DX_CLASSES where DX_CLASSES.flag = "xxx" and DX_CLASSES.ICD = have.DIAGNOSIS) as xxx
  , exists (select * from DX_CLASSES where DX_CLASSES.flag = "yyy" and DX_CLASSES.ICD = have.DIAGNOSIS) as yyy
  from DIAGNOSES as have
  ;
```

Presuming the flow

```
%macro do'ee
  emits something specific to one flag
%mend

%macro do'er
  do for each item in flags
    invoke do'ee
  end
%mend;

proc sql;
  create ... as
  select ...
  %do'er ( list of flags )
  from ...
  ;
```

The 'do-er' invocation could be

```
%apply_concepts (data=DIAGNOSES, concepts=DX_CLASS, flag=xxx yyy);
```

And a 'do-ee' (per item in flag=) invocation inside the 'do-er' implementation could be

```
%binary_flag_concept(outer=have, inner=&concepts, flag=&flag_item)
```

The 'do-ee' implementation would emit a single `exist` clause

```
, exists (
    select * 
    from &concepts as inner 
    where inner.flag = "&flag" 
      and inner.ICD = have.DIAGNOSIS
  ) as &flag
```

The outermost code could be

```
proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select have.*

  %apply_concepts (data=DIAGNOSES, concepts=DX_CLASS, flag=xxx yyy)

  from DIAGNOSES as have
  ;
```

The information in my first answer should guide *you* in coding the do'er and it's do'ee.  Create a new question, if you have any, after trying.

Note: there are numerous other ways in SAS to perform the classification lookup and application as new column.  Among those ways are formats, merges, and hash object.  And each way might also utilize the 'do-er' and 'do-ee' flow.  The most important thing is to understand the plain code version of data processing before embarking on a macroizing journey.